# is free()'ing dynamically allocated primitive arrays necessary in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic, primitive

for example, when calculating the height of a tree, see **int *heights = malloc(sizeof(int)...)**. Its recursive, so if there's a memory leak, it will be big with a large tree. I know the general rule is to use free() for every malloc, but does that apply to dynamically allocated primitive types as well?

```
typedef struct EQTNode {
    EQPos *pos;
    int genNumber;
    struct EQTNode * parent;
    int numberOfPossibleMoves;
    struct EQTNode ** children;
} EQTNode;

...

int EQTN_getHeight(EQTNode *node, int depth){
    if (node != NULL){
        int n = node->numberOfPossibleMoves;
        int *heights = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
            heights[i] = EQTN_getHeight(node->children[i], depth + 1);
        }
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
            if (heights[i] > max){
                max = heights[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    } else {
        return depth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course. Why not?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't know or care about types. If you allocate a resource at some point you should release it.

Comment: Anything you use malloc or new or new[] on, you must eventually use free or delete or delete[] respectively.

Comment: If you use the right OS, you could use alloca(), no need to free()

Comment: @user293023: No, `alloca` is *Considered Harmful* and won't even necessarily do what OP needs.

Comment: "If you use the right OS" -- If the OP used the right *algorithm* there would be no need for malloc or free ... that array is pointless.

Comment: @R.. I disagree. If you know what you are doing, and how much memory you'll be allocating, alloca() is exactly like doing int a[n], which gcc now allows. Enjoy. int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   if (2 > argc) return -1;
   int n = atoi(argv[1]);
   int a[n--];
   for (; 0 <= n; --n) {
      a[n] = n;
   }
   return 0;
}

Comment: @user293023: VLA's are also harmful for the exact same reason. There is no way for you to determine whether the allocation can be satisfied, and if it can't, you get catastrophic clobbering of unrelated memory. You can find details elsewhere (there are at least several good SO questions on the topic). In short, VLAs and `alloca` only *seem* like a magical solution to the difficulty of managing dynamic allocation until you realize you're just waving your hands and pretending nothing can go wrong. Once you understand the problem, they're worse than simply using `malloc`.

Comment: @R..Yes, pretending that nothing can go wrong is not good... but these are all valid tools and should be used wisely.

Comment: There's actually almost no way to use them wisely where normal plain fixed-size arrays couldn't do just as well, and the latter would be more obviously correct.

Comment: @user293023 One could make R..'s same argument about recursive functions with local variables ... and in fact one can simulate VLA's or alloca in terms of those. It's a futile and pedantic argument. In the real world people can establish reasonable guarantees for the size of the stack and impose reasonable constraints on their programs so they don't overflow it.

Comment: @JimBalter what is the correct algorithm for a calculating the height of a variably branched tree? (i.e. branches can have anywhere from 0 to 8 children in the program that I used this function for.)

Comment: Why don't you look at my answer? It does exactly what your code does, but without the pointless array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the type of the thing you allocate has no bearing on whether you need to free it, there's no need for the malloc/free at all:

```
if (node != NULL){
    int n = node->numberOfPossibleMoves;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int height = EQTN_getHeight(node->children[i], depth + 1);
        if (max < height)
            max = height;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Otherwise, how would the memory get freed?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case C99 enables variable length arrays so your code can be rewritten as:

```
   if (node != NULL){
        int n = node->numberOfPossibleMoves;
        int heights[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
            heights[i] = EQTN_getHeight(node->children[i], depth + 1);
        }
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1){
            if (heights[i] > max){
                max = heights[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

In this case you don't need explicitly free it.

But each `malloc()` call should have corresponding `free()` counterpart.

Comment: VLA will almost surely lead to *stack overflow* (and not the good kind) in usage cases like this.

Comment: @R That's true. There are many ways to shoot yourself in the foot with C gun. This is one of them. Not calling `free()` is another one. There are scenarios when VLA and alloca are very useful though. In recursive cases like the one described by TS VLA/alloca will look suspicious of course. But proposed usage of malloc is also looking quite dangerous. It is just that gun has tighter cock than that with VLA carved on it.

Comment: How about writing it without the heights array at all ... there's no need for it.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that you call with `malloc` should be `free`()'d by you explicitly. `malloc()` just allocates you a chunk of memory, its up to you to tell the OS when you're done using it.

Take a look at the man page for `malloc()`

[image]

C isn't garbage collected, you know ;)